# facebook manager не работает на сайте

Tags: facebook-api

Вообщем, не работает Facebook Messenger на сайте, исправно работает только в edge с chrome (отправка/ответ на сообщения). В firefox иконки мессенджера вообще не появляется;
Вставлял плагин вот так, как и выдавал facebook.

```
 <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v7.0'
          });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


      <div class="fb-customerchat"
        attribution=setup_tool
        page_id="102606368147517"
  theme_color="#6699cc"
  logged_in_greeting="Здравствуйте, в случае если вам нужна помощь. Дайте знать."
  logged_out_greeting="Здравствуйте, в случае если вам нужна помощь. Дайте знать.">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, была проблема в собственном браузере.